# using a character string of row indices to subset a data frame in R

Tags: string, r, indexing

I have a large data frame that I need to subset based on a character string of row indices provided in a single column within another table (from outside of R). These strings include several styles of index (e.g.  c(1,3), c(1:10,15), 3:10, but all are formats that should be acceptable to R. I've provided a small example here, but in practice the indices typically refer to large row chunks within a very large data frame, so I'm keen to stick with this approach if possible.

Example data:

```
my.df<-data.frame(group=c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),value=c(1,5,5,15,20,3))

set1<-"c(1,3)"

set2<-"c(1:3,5)"
```

what I'd like:

```
my.df[set1,]

group value
1     a     1
3     b     5


my.df[set2,]

group value
1     a     1
2     a     5
3     b     5
```

I can read the index strings into R successfully and convert them to a form that looks right as per the code above, but haven't been successful with the subsetting. I'm sure there's an easy trick so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the problem is the quotes around the c(...) which turns the whole thing into a character string. Just remove the quotes so that it becomes `set1<-c(1,3)`

Comment: Sorry JeremyS, I should have clarified that the reason for the quotes is that this is the text as read in from the external table. The suggestion from iugrina below solves the problem. Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
 my.df[eval(parse(text=set1)),]
```

Comment: Thanks. Solves my problem!